# Initialize a global variable with input in Rust

Tags: rust

I need to initialize a vector with a file contents and then access it (read only) from multiple threads.

Now I define it as a local variable and pass a reference to every function (see [my repo](https://github.com/dsdante/knapsack/blob/master/rust/src/main.rs#L13)), but I use it in a lightweight recursive function, so I would like to avoid passing excess parameters.

Thread-local statics won't do - I parallelize my calculations.

[lazy_static](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/lazy-static.rs/lazy_static/index.html) cannot use input for initialization, as far as I understand.

Comment: Is the file known on compile-time, or only at runtime? The former is handled by [`include`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html) and similar macros; the latter looks like a work for [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/0.2.7/once_cell/).

Comment: @Cerberus, syncronized access in `once_cell::sync::*` is an unneeded overhead for my read-only data. And the non-syncronous `once_cell::unsync::*` cannot be used as a shared global variable.

Answer (score -1):

You could define a mutable static variable.

For ex.

```rust
mut static VAR: bool = false;

fn main() {
    let input = "...";
    if input == "lorem" {
        VAR = true;
    }
}
```